# Character level keeps resetting

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm playing DD with a friend. We play "LAN" games (using Evolve), so I'm not logged into my GameSpyId account. I use the Humble version of the game, so I'm not logged into Steam either.

The problem is, when I finish playing, turn off the game normally and then start it again, my character resets to level 0 and all items I have collected in the previous run are gone too.

How can I fix this?